# make debugger stop when a value occurs Intelij Idea

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I am wondering if there is a way to search a specific value in variables while debugging.

For example, I have this code:

```
public void init(){
    int a=5;
    String s="Hello world";
    boolean enable = true;
}
```

I want to search for value "**Hello world**" in all variables. So is there a way to put this value somewhere and debugger stops at point when it finds it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use conditions in breakpoints in idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114474/how-to-use-conditions-in-breakpoints-in-idea)

Comment: Unfortunately not, but this post has interesting information. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Just create a function to aggregate all your variables?

Answer (score 2):

Add a condition in your code like:

```
if(eventOccurs){
 //put anything here
}
```

and then add the breakpoint inside the condition

Answer (score 1):

You can be following like below:

```
if(value==you want){

 //Then debug and lookup objects values that you want to check.

 System.out.println("Seting debug point of this line!")

}
```